# Linking to a font inside public directory in a css file

Tags: css, laravel, laravel-9

I have this css file called fonts.css that is inside `public/assets/css` with the following code

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Lato-light;
    src: url("{{asset('assets/fonts/Lato/Lato-Black.ttf')}}");
}
```

I ahve another file called custom.css with  the following code

```
h1 {
    font-family: Lato-light;
}
```

In my `header.blade.php` file the code is as follows

```
<link href="{{url('assets/css/fonts.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="{{url('assets/css/custom.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" rel="stylesheet" />
```

This code `src: url("{{asset('assets/fonts/Lato/Lato-Black.ttf')}}");` is not giving the laravel url its supposed to show but instead its outputting the code as it is.

Am i attaching the font correctly?

Comment: "_but instead its outputting the code as it is_" Only `.blade.php` files will be parsed by Blade. You could try to put that style inside a view file

Comment: Did you try using `@import url('another-css-file.css');`